# Problem with huge objects in a quad tree

Tags: 2d, geospatial, spatial, quadtree

Let's say I have circular objects. Each object has a diameter of 64 pixels.

The cells of my quad tree are let's say 96x96 pixels.

Everything will be fine and working well when I check collision from the cell a circle is residing in + all it's neighbor cells.

BUT what if I have one circle that has a diameter of 512 pixels? It would cover many cells and thus this would be a problem when checking only the neighbor cells. But I can't re-size my quad-tree-grid every time a much larger object is inserted into the tree...

Comment: I see no tree here. You describe a fixed size grid. A quad tree is *supposed* to contain squares of different sizes, and the number and the sizes of the cells are *supposed* to change dynamically when you add objects to your scene.

Comment: n.m: Can you elaborate? How can it be that dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an interesting problem. Maybe you can extend the node or the cell with a tree height information? If you have an object bigger then the smallest cell nest it with the tree height. That's what map's application like google or bing maps does.

Here a link to a similar solution: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/588426-2d-quadtree-collision---variety-in-size. I was confusing the screen with the quadtree. You can check collision with a simple recusion.

Comment: So I should store the object a node higher when it fully overlaps the cellsize for example? Or put the object only in a cell in which it entirely fits w/o overlapping any boundaries at all?

Comment: I'm not sure because you have moving objects. My idea is that if you store bigger objects in another height you can use this information to get the real bounds of the object. I'm not sure how you can translate this into screen address? In my tree I can use this because I store all objects in the max. height and when I don't want to see all objects I travel down the root.

Answer (score 4):

Instead och putting objects into a single cell put them in all cells they collide with. That way you can just test each cell individually. Use pointers to the object so you dont create copies. Also you only need to do this with leavenodes, so no need to combine data contained in higher nodes with lower ones.

Answer (score 1):

**Oversearching**

During the search, and starting with the largest objects first...

Test Object.Position.X against QuadTreeNode.Centre.X, and also

test Object.Position.Y against QuadTreeNode.Centre.Y;

... Then, by taking the Absolute value of the difference, treat the object as lying within a specific child node whenever the absolute value is NOT more than the radius of the object...

... that is, when some portion of the object intrudes into that quad : )

The same can be done with AABB (Axis Aligned Bounding Boxes)

The only real caveat here is that VERY large objects that cover most of the screen, will force a search of the entire tree.  In these cases, a different approach may be called for.

Of course, this only takes care of the object that everything else is being tested against.  To ensure that all the other large objects in the world are properly identified, you will need to alter your quadtree slightly...

**Use Multiple Appearances**

In this variation on the QuadTree we ONLY place objects in the leaf nodes of the QuadTree, as pointers.  Larger objects may appear in multiple leaf nodes.

Since some objects have multiple appearances in the tree, we need a way to avoid them once they've already been tested against.

So...

A simple Boolean WasHit flag can avoid testing the same object multiple times in a hit-test pass... and a 'cleanup' can be run on all 'hit' objects so that they are ready for the next test.

Whilst this makes sense, it is wasteful if performing all-vs-all hit-tests

So... Getting a little cleverer, we can avoid having any cleanup at all by using a Pointer 'ptrLastObjectTestedAgainst' inside of each object in the scene.  This avoids re-testing the same objects on this run *(the pointer is set after the first encounter)*

It does not require resetting when testing a new object against the scene *(the new object has a different pointer value than the last one)*.  This avoids the need to reset the pointer as you would with a simple Bool flag.

I've used the latter approach in scenes with vastly different object sizes and it worked well.

**Elastic QuadTrees**

I've also used an 'elastic' QuadTree.  Basically, you set a limit on how many items can IDEALLY fit in each QuadTreeNode - But, unlike a standard QuadTree, you allow the code to override this limit in specific cases.

The overriding rule here is that an object may NOT be placed into a Node that cannot hold it ENTIRELY... with the top node catching any objects that are larger than the screen.

Thus, small objects will continue to 'fall through' to form a regular QuadTree but large objects will not always fall all the way through to the leaf node - but will instead expand the node that last fitted them.

Think of the non-leaf nodes as 'sieving' the objects as they fall down the tree

This turns out to be a very efficient choice for many scenarios : )

**Conclusion**

Remember that these standard algorithms are useful general tools, but they are not a substitute for thinking about your specific problem.  Do not fall into the trap of using a specific algorithm or library 'just because it is well known' ... your application is unique, and it may benefit from a slightly different approach.

Therefore, don't just learn to *apply* algorithms ... learn *from* those algorithms, and apply the principles themselves in novel and fitting ways.  These are NOT the only tools, nor are they necessarily the best fit for your application.

Hope some of those ideas helped.